# Prove that there is some $x \in M$ ($M$ is a metric space) such that $f(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Say that $\{x_n\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ is a sequence of points in a sequentially compact metric space $(M,d)$ such that for each $n$,
$f(x_n) = \frac{1}{n}$ where $f$ is a continuous function in the metric space.

I'm trying to prove that there is some $x \in M$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

I know $\frac{1}{n}$ forms a convergent sequence, but how could it ever equal $0$.

Comment: Hint: Use compactness of $M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hints:*

1. What does the compactness of $M$ tell us about $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?
2. What does $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to?

Comment: Sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ has a limit converging to 0.  A metric space M is sequentially compact if every sequence of points
in M has a convergent subsequence converging to a point in M.

Comment: Is it as simple as saying that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to 0 for some point $x \in M$ because every sequence (Xn) in M converges to some point and the given function has a known limit.

Comment: you've almost got it! However, we don't know that $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges -- only that it has a subsequence $(x_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to a point in $x\in M$. But, since $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ goes to $0$, all of its subsequences also go to $0$ and hence so does $(1/k_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. This is also only possible due to the continuity of $f$.